# Convert TIFF to jpg using ImageMagick in terminal on Yosemite

Tags: graphics, imagemagick, jpeg, tiff

I've got a directory filled with `tif` files that I'm trying to convert to `jpg` format.

```
for i in *.tif ; do convert "$i" "${i%.*}.jpg" ; done
```

I'm using ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 installed via `brew` on Yosemite in Terminal.

I'm not looking to do anything fancy, just convert from one format to another. I've check to ensure I have the tif delegate installed. I've looked here and on Google, Bing, etc., yet I can't get a command to work.

Comment: What does not work? Imagemagick or you shell script?

Comment: What happens when you run the command? The `for` loop should work, so maybe try using `convert` on a single file to see what the result is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved. After installing, reinstalling, adding delegates, etc., I discovered:

```
brew doctor
```

I followed the prompts, ran the commands it recommended. I discovered I had a lot of stuff that was out of date, incorrect dependencies, stuff that needed pruning, etc.

I finally did this:

`brew uninstall imagemagick`

`brew install libtiff` (even though I had it previously)

`brew install imagemagick`

I ran the very same command in my original query and rather than giving me a `>` prompt and doing nothing until I pressed `ctrl+c`, the command ran and converted my files.

[How I felt when it worked.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N0OHdRFcJA)